# Check if One of Two GET Variables Has a Certain Value

Tags: php

I know how to do this with one GET variable, but I don't want to define each variable twice. Here is the code:

```
if($_GET['var1']=='one'){
    $name = "Item Name";
    $image = "one.jpg";
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is check `var1` OR `var2` for `one`

Is this possible?

Comment: So why don't you use `OR`, e.g. `if($_GET['var1']=='one' || $_GET['var2'] == 'two'){` ?

Comment: @Rizier123 I thought of this option but I will be checking both variables for the exact same thing, so instead of using an OR statement and using the same value of `one` in both, I'm trying to see if its possible to check for `one` without using the OR statement above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, you can simply use:

```
if(in_array('one', [$_GET['var1'], $_GET['var2']])) {}
```

To do the check without using `||`

Answer (score 0):

Yesh, certainly. Simply do

```
if($_GET['var1']=='one' || $_GET['var2'] == 'one'){
    $name = "Item Name";
    $image = "one.jpg";
}
```

This is called an `OR` statement. More info about logical operators in PHP can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: this is what I'm trying to avoid: `if($_GET['var1']=='one' || $_GET['var2'] == 'one'){` is there any way to check both `var1` and `var2` without defining both? I just want to check `one` without using an OR statement like this

Comment: `if(in_array('one', [$_GET['arg1'], $_GET['arg2']]))` like that? Otherwise not sure how you'd want to simplify it...

Comment: @Jon that looks more of what I'm looking for, I'll test it now

Comment: @Jon can you respond as an answer so i can checkmark it? the code you suggested is what seems to be working the way i want it to